# How to parse JsArary in scala?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have following JSON in JsArray(or String) in Scala.

```
[
  {
    "row1": [
      {
        "seatId": "R1",
        "seatStatus": "BOOKED",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      },
      {
        "seatId": "R3",
        "seatStatus": "AVAILABLE",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "row2": [
      {
        "seatId": "R1",
        "seatStatus": "BOOKED",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      },
      {
        "seatId": "R3",
        "seatStatus": "AVAILABLE",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "row3": [
      {
        "seatId": "R1",
        "seatStatus": "BOOKED",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      },
      {
        "seatId": "R3",
        "seatStatus": "AVAILABLE",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      },
      {
        "seatId": "R3",
        "seatStatus": "AVAILABLE",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

where row1,row2,row3 can vary according to call, sometimes it can be row1-5 or maybe row1-4. How can I parse this JSON?  How can I extract row1, row2 and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to parse the array as a `Vector[JsObject]` and then use whatever the key (row1,row2,row3,...) is as a field in a case class `Row` and parse the inner array as a `Vector` of seats.

For the following code, please note that *I did no error handling*!  You don't want to just use the `.as` method, but instead use for example `validate` and the same goes for the unsafe `.head` call when building the `Row` class.  Having said that,

here is an ammonite script that does exactly that:

```
import $ivy.`com.typesafe.play::play-json:2.6.7`

import play.api.libs.json._

case class Row(name: String, seats: Vector[Seat])

case class Seat(seatId: String, seatStatus: String, seatIsLadies: Boolean)

object Seat {
  implicit def format: Format[Seat] = Json.format[Seat]
}

  val inputJson = """
[
  {
    "row1": [
      {
        "seatId": "R1",
        "seatStatus": "BOOKED",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      },
      {
        "seatId": "R3",
        "seatStatus": "AVAILABLE",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "row2": [
      {
        "seatId": "R1",
        "seatStatus": "BOOKED",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      },
      {
        "seatId": "R3",
        "seatStatus": "AVAILABLE",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "row3": [
      {
        "seatId": "R1",
        "seatStatus": "BOOKED",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      },
      {
        "seatId": "R3",
        "seatStatus": "AVAILABLE",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      },
      {
        "seatId": "R3",
        "seatStatus": "AVAILABLE",
        "seatIsLadies": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
"""

val json = Json.parse(inputJson)

val rowObjs = json.as[Vector[JsObject]]

val result = rowObjs.map(obj => Row(obj.fields.head._1, obj.fields.head._2.as[Vector[Seat]]))

println(result)
```

Which results in the output:

```
Vector(
  Row(row1,Vector(Seat(R1,BOOKED,false), Seat(R3,AVAILABLE,false))), 
  Row(row2,Vector(Seat(R1,BOOKED,false), Seat(R3,AVAILABLE,false))), 
  Row(row3,Vector(Seat(R1,BOOKED,false), Seat(R3,AVAILABLE,false),Seat(R3,AVAILABLE,false)))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [recursive path operator **\\**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson#Recursive-path-%5C%5C)

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class RowValue(seatId: String, seatStatus: String, seatIsLadies: Boolean)
object RowValue {
  implicit val rowFormat: Format[RowValue] = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[RowValue]
}
// in json is your json string
val js: JsValue = Json.parse(json)
val rowNames: Seq[String] = Seq[String]("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4", "row5")
rowNames.foreach { r =>
  val rowValues = (js \\ r).map(x => x.asOpt[Seq[RowValue]])
  println(s"$r => $rowValues")
}
```

Output will be:

```
row1 => ArrayBuffer(Some(List(RowValue(R1,BOOKED,false), RowValue(R3,AVAILABLE,false))))
row2 => ArrayBuffer(Some(List(RowValue(R1,BOOKED,false), RowValue(R3,AVAILABLE,false))))
row3 => ArrayBuffer(Some(List(RowValue(R1,BOOKED,false), RowValue(R3,AVAILABLE,false), RowValue(R3,AVAILABLE,false))))
row4 => ArrayBuffer()
row5 => ArrayBuffer()
```